# Draggable rectangle thumb on a WPF slider - Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, wpf-controls, desktop-application

We have got a requirement where we have to use a WPF slider control. Attached a screenshot of requirement for better understanding.
And we want the thumb style to display like a rectangle to show the selected value on it. In that we have a combobox with some values(like 1kHz, 2kHz, 3kHz,…).
When we select any value from combobox, the sider thumb width should be the selected combobox value and selected value should be displayed on the thumb.

Please suggest us a way to implement this.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: [WPF Move element with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380682/wpf-move-element-with-mouse). Just set only the x-value and keep the y-value.

Comment: This looks more like a `Slider` control paired with a ComboBox.  You could write a `UserControl` that simply contains both instead of a `CustomControl`  Give it the bindable `DependencyProperty`-s (e.g. Value, Min, Max, etc) that you need to customize the slider and combo and make the XAML bind to those.  Unless you need to style it.  Then you probably want to write a `ControlTemplate` for `Slider`  As for how to write a control -- well that's a documentation thing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.