# Use the TranslateTransform and ScaleTransform of the Canvas or those of the Geometry shape while creating Custom Canvas Zoom and Pan?

Tags: c#, canvas, cad

I'm trying to create a custom Canvas by inherit from Canvas with the so famous feature Zoom and Pan.
I succeeded to Pan and Zoom using the mouse events (move and wheel), BUT : all the canvas (in my case black background) moved and not only my few shapes.
it's about the global Pan and Zoom and not drag&Drop one shape

so I added a custom Shape inherited from shape like this :

```
public class DataShape : Shape, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public int ID;
        public Geometry DataShapeGeometry;
     
        public ScaleTransform ShapeScaleTransfrom;
        public TranslateTransform ShapeTranslateTransform;  
        public TransformGroup ShapeTransformGroup;  

      
        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry { get { return DataShapeGeometry; } }

       
        public DataShape()
        {
           
            
            DataShapeGeometry = new LineGeometry(); // just to not having Null object that prevent creation of " DataShapeGeometry.Transform "

            ShapeTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();

            ShapeTranslateTransform = new TranslateTransform(); 
            ShapeScaleTransfrom = new ScaleTransform(); 
            ShapeTransformGroup.Children.Add(ShapeTranslateTransform);
            ShapeTransformGroup.Children.Add(ShapeScaleTransfrom);

            DataShapeGeometry.Transform = ShapeTransformGroup;
}
```

for the Custom Canvas I have this (part of the code)
first I used the _pan TranslateTransform as a global Transform, as I said it worked but all my Canvas moved, then i wonted to use the shapeTranslateTransform and the shapeScalTransform , no reaction but i confirmed that the values incremente properly (the zoom geting bigger and bigger , same for the offset, i even used a Textbox to show that :))

```
public class ZoomPanCanvas : Canvas
    {
        public static int Global_ID = 0;
        public MainWindow w1;
        public List<DataShape> selectedDataShapes;
        public DataShape selectedShape; 

        private Point? dragStartPoint = null;
        private Matrix transform = Matrix.Identity;
        private TranslateTransform _pan = new TranslateTransform();

        public ZoomPanCanvas()
        {
            this.RenderTransform = _pan;
            this.MouseWheel += ZoomPanCanvas_MouseWheel;
            this.MouseLeftButtonDown += ZoomPanCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            this.MouseMove += ZoomPanCanvas_MouseMove;
            this.MouseLeftButtonUp += ZoomPanCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        }


       
       
        
        public void RedrawAll()
        {
            this.InvalidateArrange();
        }







        #region EVENTS_METHOD 



        private void ZoomPanCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            dragStartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
        }
        bool b = false;int j = 0;
        private void ZoomPanCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Point point = e.GetPosition(this);

                /* this was working <--------------------------------------
                _pan.X += point.X - dragStartPoint.Value.X;
                _pan.Y += point.Y - dragStartPoint.Value.Y;*/

               


                foreach (UIElement datashape in this.Children)
                {
                   
                        // it works we need to pan each shape
                        selectedShape = datashape as DataShape;
                        ((TranslateTransform) (selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[0])).X += point.X - dragStartPoint.Value.X;
                        ((TranslateTransform)(selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[0])).Y += point.Y - dragStartPoint.Value.Y;
                        
                        //((selectedShape.DataShapeGeometry.Transform)as TranslateTransform).X += point.X - dragStartPoint.Value.X;
                        // ((selectedShape.DataShapeGeometry.Transform) as TranslateTransform).Y += point.Y - dragStartPoint.Value.Y;


                   
                    

                }

                dragStartPoint = point;
            }
        }

        private void ZoomPanCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            dragStartPoint = null;
        }

        private void ZoomPanCanvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
            // scale get only two values, it does'nt increment !
            double scale = e.Delta > 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1);
            //this.transform.ScaleAt(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);
            //this.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(this.transform);

            


            foreach (UIElement datashape in this.Children)
            {
                
                    // it works we need to pan each shape
                    selectedShape = datashape as DataShape;
                    //selectedShape.DataShapeGeometry.Transform.Value.Scale(scale, scale);

                    ((ScaleTransform)(selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[1])).ScaleX = ((ScaleTransform)(selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[1])).ScaleX * scale;
                    ((ScaleTransform)(selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[1])).ScaleY = ((ScaleTransform)(selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[1])).ScaleY * scale;
                    w1.TXT1.Text = ((ScaleTransform)(selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[1])).ScaleX.ToString();
                    



                


            }

        } 
        #endregion
    }
```

I trayed to apply the GroupTransform to initialize all types of transform (Translate for Pan andScale for Zoom) in the Datashape Constructor.
I reached "selectedShape.ShapeTransformGroup.Children[]" from inside my ZoomPanCanvas i confirmed that values change but no impact in the interface.

I dare have a great expectation to create a sort of intelligent Cad Canvas (or like visio ).
I will not use ItemsControl, it's useful but when dealing with Algorithmic Geometry I prefer a straightforward simple canvas.

Many thanks

Comment: Tip: Look for the CaptureMouse/ReleaseMouse for moving controls, this allows you to move the control but don't lose movement outside the canvas. See [WPF Move element with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380682/wpf-move-element-with-mouse/56785902#56785902)

Comment: many thanks but i'm not looking for moving shapes at one by one, i need a global move for all shapes at once now as Pan feature.